# Run an app from a subfolder in the public folder of a Laravel app

Tags: laravel

I need to install a custom app in a subfolder of my site, and make that publicly accessible. Like `mysite.com/results`, where inside the `results` folder will be a custom JS app responsible for displaying results of some running / cycling events.

**Update**
By custom JS app I mean a bunch of files that comes from the race timing software I use, so I have no control of the files there, just need to be able to make them accessible.

If I create an `index.html` in that folder, it works, but if I create an `index.php` it does not work.

I use Valet on my dev machine and my website is being deployed with Ploi deploy.

Comment: when you run index.php what error is displayed?

Comment: No erros, it just loads the website, but no images are displayed

Comment: You can use a modern javascript framework like react or vue. Have a look at how you might build one of those apps and you can use Laravel as an API if required.

Alternatively, create a view which is rendered by your laravel application when the `/results` route is requested, which loads a javascript file in your blade template. From there you can use it as an entrypoint to something more complex like a react or vue application.

Comment: The situation here is the installation of laravel into subdir. Why? because laravel public components are supposed to be called from documento root. For example, in subdir you call your js/css/images files like `mysite.com/results/public/style.css`